# What is the least positive integer $m$ such that $\text{rank} A^m=\text{rank} A^{m+1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a complex square matrix. What is the least positive integer $m$ such that $\text{rank} A^m=\text{rank} A^{m+1}$? Express $m$ in terms of some quantities associated with $A$.

Comment: Could you clarify what is $A$?

Comment: $A$ is a complex square matrix.

Comment: If $A$ is invertible, then $m=1$.

Comment: $m$ is required to be positive.

Comment: Can you give a general formula, regardless of the invertibility of $A$?

Comment: Why do you think there is a "general" formula ? Also for $A=0$ we obtain $m=1$.

Comment: The rank of a matrix is the dimension of the image. Each successive application of $A$ might collapse another dimension (or more), or it might not. In any case, after $n$ applications it _must_ have stabilised at a certain dimension (if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix).

Comment: If $A$ is nilpotent of order $\rho$, then $m=\rho$.

Comment: @Martigan: Indeed. In the nilpotent case can you express your nilpotent order in terms of other quantities associated to $A$? What about the general case?

Comment: @Arthur: Indeed $n$ is an upper bound for $m$ but in most of the cases it is a crude one.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Your comment about invertible $A$ is wrong: for that case $m=0$, not $m=1$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: $m$ is required to be positive in my question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde. Care to explain? $A^0=I$ always has maximal rank, and $A^1=A$ has so if and only if $A$ is invertible, so I get $m=0$ iff $A$ is invertible. I take the stipulation that $m$ is to be (strictly) positive to be an error in the question. Yes, one could take the answer to be $\max(1,\text{the true answer})$, but it would be ridiculous to thus suggest that the invertible case is comparable to the case where $0$ is a true eigenvalue but has geometric multiplicity equal to algebraic multiplicity.

Comment: Yes, I had this insight myself. However, my comment is not wrong. The minimal positive $m$ is indeed $1$, if $0$ is excluded.

Answer (score 2):

The number $m$ is the multiplicity of $0$ as root of the minimal polynomial$~\mu$ of$~A$. It is therefore the degree of the lowest nonzero term of$~\mu$  (which term always exists since $\mu$ is monic). It is also equal to the size of the largest Jordan block for the eigenvalue$~0$ (if there are any; if not then it is$~0$).

In particular it is $0$ if $A$ is invertible, or equivalently if the minimal polynomial has nonzero constant term. It is at most equal to the size$~n$ of the matrix, which limit is attained for nilpotent matrices having just one Jordan block.

---

If you insist (as OP apparently does) that $m$ be strictly positive, then take the maximum of the number above and $1$. Similarly, if you insist that $m$ be at least $7$, take $\max(7,\text{the true answer})$. Generalize to any arbitrarily imposed lower bound, and prove by induction if you feel so inclined. As for me I find such a gratuitous limitation counterproductive, and refuse to give the right answer to the wrong question.

Comment: @AlexFok: See my extension. I hope you are happy with it.

Comment: I don't see why my question is wrong in the first place. The positivity assumption is not unnatural since I want to see when the sequence $\text{rank} A, \text{rank} A^2,\cdots$ stabilizes, without prior knowledge of invertibility of $A$.

Comment: What is more, in the invertible case if you lift the positivity assumption there's no least $m$ because, using your convention, $m$ can be any negative integer. You could have pointed out that a better assumption would be the nonnegativity one which your solution fits into, instead of saying my question is wrong without clear explanation in a blunt and sarcastic tone which I did not expect in this forum.

Comment: @AlexFok Without prior knowledge of the invertibility of $A$, the sequence $A^0=I,A,A^2,\ldots$ is well defined (by contrast $A^{-1}$ is not), and it would be natural to ask where their ranks first stabilise. Since having equal ranks at positions $m,m+1$ implies having equal ranks at positions $m+1,m+2$, the answer to that question immediately implies the answer to your question, where $A^0$ is omitted; however the latter answer does not always imply the answer to the natural question. So the answer to the natural question is more informative; it is also in all respects more straightforward.

Comment: ...Indeed any answer formulation I can think of (and I gave three variants in my first paragraph) suggests that the answer wants to be $0$ if (and only if) $A$ is invertible. You can force it to be$~1$ for that case, but one could also take this as an indication that maybe excluding $m=0$ is artificial. You have of course the right to ask the question in whatever way you like, as anybody has the right to answer it in whatever way they like, or not answer at all. I apologise if my tone hurt your sensitivity; it might have been different without your (now deleted) comment "you are almost there".